# How to get data from 2 different tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables User_Posts

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `User_Posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `wall_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `text` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `img` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `time` date NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

User_Activity

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `User_Activity` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` varchar(55) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `activity_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `activity` varchar(88) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `time` date NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=131 ;
```

And i want to get all activities and posts where user_id = ?

Tried to do it with

```
$act = $this->app->db->rawQuery("SELECT p.*, a.*
                                 FROM User_Posts p 
                                 JOIN User_Activity a
                                 ON a.user_id = ? OR p.user_id = ?", array($id,$id));
```

I'm getting data like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 130
            [user_id] => 16
            [wall_id] => 0
            [text] => 'Text'
            [img] => 0
            [time] => 2014-10-31
            [deleted] => 0
            [content] => movie
            [activity_id] => 5
            [activity] => favorite
            [value] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 130
            [user_id] => 16
            [wall_id] => 0
            [text] => 'Text'
            [img] => /posts/ceee9b387dcf72bcb19d1c1c73147ef3.jpg
            [time] => 2014-10-31
            [deleted] => 0
            [content] => movie
            [activity_id] => 5
            [activity] => favorite
            [value] => 0
        )

)
```

But I need

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [user_id] => 16
            [wall_id] => 0
            [text] => 'Text'
            [img] => 0
            [time] => 2014-10-31
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [user_id] => 16
            [wall_id] => 0
            [text] => 'Text'
            [img] => /posts/ceee9b387dcf72bcb19d1c1c73147ef3.jpg
            [time] => 2014-10-31
        )

      [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 130
            [content] => movie
            [activity_id] => 5
            [activity] => favorite
            [value] => 0
        )

)
```

response is posts with appended activities But i need different results for each one

how to do it?

Comment: What you try to do is impossible. All rows returned from a query must have the same columns.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small modification

```
$act = $this->app->db->rawQuery("SELECT p.*, a.*
                             FROM User_Posts p, User_Activity a
                             WHERE a.user_id = p.user_id
                             AND p.user_id = ?", array($id));
```

Comment: I'm getting the same result rows from User_Posts with appended row from User_Activity

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `JOIN` keyword.

```
SELECT *
FROM User_Posts, User_Activity 
WHERE `User_Activity`.`User_id` = `User_Posts`.`user_id`
```

Comment: This is a join, only another syntax.

Comment: am getting the same, changed question and view it again what I'm getting

Comment: @nvanesch, yes it joins two tables, but it does not use a `JOIN`. Correcting my grammar is not conducive to answering the question. If you feel like you can make the answer more clear, edit it.